# Multiple path for Base Media URL

Tags: performance, media

I want to load my media/images from multiple cdn path to decrease the download time of my category/product pages.

Currently there is only one field to enter the `base media url`. Any plugin or any useful tips on this will be a great help.

My requirement is i should be able to give more than one base media url paths from Magento admin. (I know how to give more fields there).This is not my real problem. But I would like to tweak my Magento to load media assets from those base media urls i have configured in admin.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what expectation you have how Magento is supposed to make use of those multiple fields, but...

you can add fields to the system configuration by using a system.xml. Here some good tutorials for that:

- [Magento Wiki](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/admin/xml_structure_for_admin_configurations)
- [alanstorm.com](http://alanstorm.com/custom_magento_system_configuration)
- [<strike>ecomdev.org</strike>](http://www.ecomdev.org/2010/10/27/custom-configuration-fields-in-magento.html)

But adding the fields won't do anything if you don't use them in your own blocks and templates, cause all Magento will do is store them. I don't know of any easy way to do this.

Comment: am not talking about adding fields in admin. It should load my media assets from those path i have give in round robin. please read my question one more time

Comment: Yes, I figured just adding the fields wouldn't do. I pondered this a bit and if you want magento to manage that automatically by some rules you define, I think it should be possible to rewrite the get getMediaUrl and related methods in `Class Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Media_Config`